# UWP Exception when binding to ComboBox

Tags: xaml, combobox, uwp

I am getting this exception:

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred in AppName.exe

This occurs only when I Bind to a `ComboBox`
Here's my XAML:

```
<ContentDialog x:Name="BrowseBySourceDialog"                                   
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   PrimaryButtonText="Accept" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="False"          
                                   Opened="BrowseBySourceDialog_Opened">

                        <StackPanel  Background="White">
                                <Border Background="DarkGreen" MinHeight="40"
                                           MinWidth="300">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Browse: By Source"                     
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Foreground="White"        
                                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Border>
                            <StackPanel>

                                <ComboBox x:Name="BrowseBySourceComboBox" 
                                          PlaceholderText="Select Source"                      
                                          Height="40" 
                                          Width="300" 
                                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind BrowseBySourceList, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Source">
                                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:FeaturedResponseItem">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind key}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ContentDialog>
```

This exception only occurs when the following lines are present:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:FeaturedResponseItem">
           <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind key}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

If the remove the above lines, the combobox surely remains empty but the exception doesn't occur. Is the binding wrong?

Source:

```
ObservableCollection<FeaturedResponseItem> BrowseBySourceList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FeaturedResponseItem>();
```

Model:

```
public class FeaturedResponseItem
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public bool accessible { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `Source`?

Comment: @JustinXL updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete `DisplayMemberPath="Source"` or simply just remove the `ItemTemplate` all together and change `DisplayMemberPath="Source"` to `DisplayMemberPath="Key"`.